# Test effect of Redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux

I have a React modal component that shows/hides depending on a variable that can be set/changed via a Redux dispatch.

I am at a bit of a loss of how to actually test it though.

Any help is appreciated.

**Action**

```
const HIDE_MODAL = 'HIDE_MODAL';

export const hideModal = () => ({
    type: HIDE_MODAL
});
```

**Reducer**

```
// import HIDE_MODAL

export default (state = {}, action) => {
    let newState = deepClone(state);

    switch (action.type) {
       case HIDE_MODAL:
            newState.showModal = false;
            break;

       default:
            return state;
    }

    return newState;
}
```

**Component**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    showModal: state.showModal
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    closeModal: () => dispatch(hideModal)
});

const MyComponent = ({closeModal, showModal}) => {
    if (showModal) {
        return <div>
           <div>My Modal</div>

           <button onClick={closeModal}/>Close</button>
        </div>
    }
);
```

**Test**

```
it('Should hide modal on click', () => {
    const store = {showModal: true};

    render(
        <Provider store={mockStore(store)}>
            <MyComponent />
        </Provider>
    );

    expect(screen.queryByText('My modal')).toBeTruthy();

    userEvent.click(screen.queryByText('Close'));

    expect(screen.queryByText('My modal')).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should set your default value of `showModal` to `true` for testing purposes. If I'm not mistaken your function `closeModal` should be a little bit changes to this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    closeModal: () => dispatch(hideModal()),
});
```

Because `hideModal` is a function you should call it too.

```
export const hideModal = () => ({
    type: HIDE_MODAL
});
```

Otherwise you should pass an action directly to your `dispatch` `Redux` function(because `dispatch` takes an object with at least `type` key as an argument for proper work):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    closeModal: () => dispatch({
        type: HIDE_MODAL
    }),
});
```

Hope it will help.